# Как сделать, чтобы при клике на MORE/BACK переключалась только одна конкретная карточка, а не все сразу на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая, упрощенная для примера,  разметка карточек товара:

```
<section class="cards_wrapper">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face">
            <img class="picture" src="img/meter.png" alt="">
            <p class="more link">MORE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
            <p class="back link">BACK</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face">
            <img class="picture" src="img/size.png" alt="">
            <p class="more link">MORE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
            <p class="back link">BACK</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="face">
            <img class="picture" src="img/weighing-scale.png" alt="">
            <p class="more link">MORE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
            <p class="back link">BACK</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Пробный JS:

```
const cardsLink = document.querySelectorAll(".link");
const cardsFace = document.querySelectorAll(".face");

cardsLink.forEach(cLink => {
    cLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
        cardsFace.forEach(cFace => {
            cFace.classList.toggle("on");
        });
    });
});
```

css:

```
.on {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на MORE/BACK переключалась только одна конкретная карточка, а не все сразу? Должно быть много карточек. Нужно реализовать на чистом JS без jQuery.
В JS знания пока очень поверхностные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данный цикл производит изменения для всех элементов, её нужно убрать.

```
cardsFace.forEach(cFace => {
    cFace.classList.toggle("on");
});
```

Вместо неё можно использовать `this` обращаясь к активному элементу, тем самым мы получим или  `<p class="more link">MORE</p>`, или же `<p class="back link">BACK</p>`. А дальше уже используя `parentElement` и `querySelector` находим нужен элемент и задаём свойства. 
Тем самым получим:

```
this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.face').classList.toggle("on");
```

А вот конечный, полный код:

```
const cardsLink = document.querySelectorAll(".link");

cardsLink.forEach(cLink => {
  cLink.addEventListener("click", function() {          
    this.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.face').classList.toggle("on");
  });
});
```

Comment: Только вместо `this.parentElement.parentElement` думаю лаконичнее будет использовать `this.closest('.card')`. Но это дело вкуса

Comment: Оба примера конечно работают. Хотелось бы понять, почему parentElement нужно повторять 2 раза.

Comment: ```parentElement``` обращается к родителю, стоящему выше на 1 ветку. А поскольку обработчик будет работать как для ```MORE```, так и для ```BACK``` кнопок, то нужно из-за структуры обратиться к элементу ```<div class="card">``` и уже внутри него искать элемент ```<div class="face">```. Если бы обработчик писался под кнопки по отдельности, то ```parentElement``` 1 раз нужно было писать для кнопки ```MORE``` и 2 раза для кнопки ```BACK```.

Comment: ```closest``` это тоже самое, что ```parentElement```, но обращается к родителю стоящему выше по ветке (без разницы на сколько).

Comment: Возникли дополнительные проблемы в JS. Еще раз поможете?

Comment: Да, в чем проблема?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1371041/Как-по-клику-на-кнопку-менять-текст-в-параграфе-модального-окна/1371050#1371050

Comment: Сделал ошибку при упрощении HTML. Теперь поправил. Заранее спасибо за помощь.