# Как по клику на кнопку менять текст в параграфе модального окна?

Tags: javascript, modal

Как сделать, чтобы при клике на button "Купить", в параграф **p class="model_modal"** модального окна подставлялся текст (№ модели) из карточки **class="card"**?
Пробовал textContent.replace и всякое другое, но знаний в JS не хватает.

```
    <section class="cards_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face">
                <img class="picture" src="img/meter.png" alt="">
                <p class="model">Модель №1</p>
                <p class="more link">MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
                <p class="back link">BACK</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button">Купить</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="cards_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face">
                <img class="picture" src="img/meter.png" alt="">
                <p class="model">Модель №2</p>
                <p class="more link">MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
                <p class="back link">BACK</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button">Купить</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="cards_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face">
                <img class="picture" src="img/meter.png" alt="">
                <p class="model">Модель №3</p>
                <p class="more link">MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
                <p class="back link">BACK</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button">Купить</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="modals_wrapper">
        <div class="modal_3">
            <p class="model_modal">Конкретная модель</p>
            <form class="form"></form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Пробный JS:

```
    const buyButton = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
    const buyModel = document.querySelectorAll(".model");

    buyButton.forEach(function (bt) {
        bt.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        // Дальше ничего не получалось
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удобнее сделать так.

```js
const buyBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

buyBtns.forEach(buyBtn => {
  buyBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.querySelector(".model_modal").innerHTML = this.closest('.cards_wrapper').querySelector('.model').innerHTML;
  });
});
```

```html
   <section class="cards_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face">
                <img class="picture" src="img/meter.png" alt="">
                <p class="model">Модель №1</p>
                <p class="more link">MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
                <p class="back link">BACK</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button">Купить</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="cards_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face">
                <img class="picture" src="img/meter.png" alt="">
                <p class="model">Модель №2</p>
                <p class="more link">MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
                <p class="back link">BACK</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button">Купить</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="cards_wrapper">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="face">
                <img class="picture" src="img/meter.png" alt="">
                <p class="model">Модель №3</p>
                <p class="more link">MORE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</h3>
                <p class="back link">BACK</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card_footer">
            <button class="button">Купить</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="modals_wrapper">
        <div class="modal_3">
            <p class="model_modal">Конкретная модель</p>
            <form class="form"></form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

`document.querySelector(".model_modal").innerHTML` - данный код отвечает за смену данных внутри блока с классом `model_modal`. 
`this.closest('.cards_wrapper').querySelector('.model').innerHTML` - данная часть кода отвечает за взятие данных у карточки.